# Django values_list return list of dict

Tags: django, django-models

I tried to return my querset objects as list of unique items using ,

```
return qs.values_list(distinct_val, flat=True)
```

if i **print** above query it gives `['val1','val2', etc]` values as a list. but when i suppose to return my output look like this,

```
[
    {},
    {
        "name": null,
        "id": null
    },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

required output is,

```
['Fredrick', 'Mohi', ]
```

instead,

```
[
  {'name': 'Fredrick'}
]
```

where i made mistake?

**my query:**

```
val = qs.values_list(distinct_val, flat=True).distinct().order_by()
print val
return val
```

**My print statement:**

```
[u'Frederick', None, u'Leslie', u'Francine']
```

**My Response:**

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

**my Custom ViewSet:**

```
class DjangoFilterBackendExt(DjangoFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        qs = super(DjangoFilterBackendExt, self).filter_queryset(request, queryset, view)
        distinct_val = request.query_params.get('distinct')
        if distinct_val:
            return qs.values(distinct_val).distinct()
        return qs
```

Comment: Do you realize that `values` and `values_list` are two different methods and both are behaving as documented?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert Queryset to list()

```
return list(qs.values_list(distinct_val, flat=True))
```

Comment: tried already not working.. if print i am getting but when i return qs became weird

Comment: in which method you have this return statement?, if you overrided `get_queryset()` then you can not return a list from there. you have to find other workaround, if you can explain why you needed list then i can help

Comment: i am overriding filter_queryset... slightly updated my question. i wish to reduce frontend complication.. in front end i am using underscorejs to convert dict to list. i a just trying the same in backend

Comment: You can change reponse data before sending but `filter_queryset` is not the place to do it.

Comment: Post your django view

Comment: You posted filter_class not viewset